# HttpException (0x80004005): Session data is too long

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, web-applications

My Web application using MVC 3 and I get this error:

> Session data is too long.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Session data is too long.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Session data is too long.]
>   System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider.SaveItemToSession(Session
>   session, SessionStateStoreData item, Boolean compression, Int32
>   maxLength) +205
>   System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext
>   context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean
>   newItem) +534
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object
>   source, EventArgs eventArgs) +1021
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +80    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18447

I've tried to google but no-one got it before.

Below is my web.config file, maybe problem from here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="RetryPolicyConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.Configuration.RetryPolicyConfigurationSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling, Version=5.1.1209.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="typeRegistrationProvidersConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.TypeRegistrationProvidersConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <sectionGroup name="telerik">
      <section name="webAssets" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebAssetConfigurationSection, Telerik.Web.Mvc" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
    ...
  </configSections>
  <RetryPolicyConfiguration defaultRetryStrategy="Fixed Interval Retry Strategy">
    <incremental name="Incremental Retry Strategy" />
    <fixedInterval name="Fixed Interval Retry Strategy" />
    <exponentialBackoff name="Exponential Backoff Retry Strategy" />
  </RetryPolicyConfiguration>
  <typeRegistrationProvidersConfiguration>
    <clear />
    <add name="Caching" sectionName="cachingConfiguration" />
    <add name="Cryptography" sectionName="securityCryptographyConfiguration" />
    <add name="Exception Handling" sectionName="exceptionHandling" />
    <add name="Instrumentation" sectionName="instrumentationConfiguration" />
    <add name="Logging" sectionName="loggingConfiguration" />
    <add name="Policy Injection" sectionName="policyInjection" />
    <add name="Security" sectionName="securityConfiguration" />
    <add name="Data Access" providerType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSyntheticConfigSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data" />
    <add name="Validation" providerType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Configuration.ValidationTypeRegistrationProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation" />
    <add sectionName="RetryPolicyConfiguration" name="RetryPolicyConfiguration" />
  </typeRegistrationProvidersConfiguration>
  <connectionStrings>
    ...
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="RunScheduler" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="100000" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="asset.axd" validate="false" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.WebAssetHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.Mvc" />
      <add type="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.14.225, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" path="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.14.225, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" />
        <add assembly="Telerik.Reporting, Version=8.0.14.225, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/Login.aspx" timeout="15" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="VPAdmin.Common" />
        <add namespace="VPAdmin.Models" />
        <add namespace="VPAdmin.ViewModels" />
        <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="15">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers" connectionStringName="VisionPOS_masterConnectionString" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Elfo.Infrastructure.Service.WCF.WcfRequestProcessor" behaviorConfiguration="RequestProcessorBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" contract="Elfo.Infrastructure.Service.WCF.IWcfRequestProcessor" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RequestProcessorBinding" />
        <endpoint address="json" contract="Elfo.Infrastructure.Service.WCF.IWcfRestJsonRequestProcessor" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" />
        <endpoint address="jsonp" contract="Elfo.Infrastructure.Service.WCF.IWcfRestJsonRequestProcessor" bindingConfiguration="webBindingWithJsonP" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <client>
      ...
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBindingWithJsonP" />
      </webHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="RequestProcessorBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RequestProcessorBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1000000" maxConcurrentInstances="1000000" maxConcurrentSessions="1000000" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="RequestProcessorBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      ...
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="asset" />
      <add name="asset" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="asset.axd" type="Telerik.Web.Mvc.WebAssetHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.Mvc" />
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <add name="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd_*" type="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.14.225, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" path="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Drawing" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Core" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Configuration" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Services" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.Linq" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <telerik>
    <webAssets useTelerikContentDeliveryNetwork="false" />
  </telerik>
  <!-- logging configuration -->
  <log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="100" />
      ...
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date{yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff}" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@hostname" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%property" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@app_domain" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%appdomain" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%thread" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%level" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%logger" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%message" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ERROR" />
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <ServiceConfiguration>
    <!--database setting-->
    ...
    <!--report setting-->
    <ReportSettings noCrystalReport="False" printer="" labelPrinter="" />
    <!--device setting-->
    <DeviceSettings cashDrawer="" steriaLogLevel="0" />
    <!--app setting-->
    <ApplicationSettings debug="False" upgradeLevel="" disableSemiTransparency="False" backgroundColorStart="-9273198" backgroundColorEnd="-13880261" syncInterval="864000000" noCount="False" />
  </ServiceConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

When I change this line:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="15">
```

to:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="15">
```

it work perfect but I need to use session to publish to Windows Azure.

Can anyone help me or give me some idea?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with this part:

> When I change this line:
>
> ```
> <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="15">
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="15">
> ```
>
> it work perfect but I need to use session to publish to Windows Azure.

Out of process session state must be serialized so that it can travel across process boundaries. For example, serialization enables the data to be inserted into a SQL Server table as an array of bytes.

Based on the error message, there appears to be a maximum size to the serialized representation of your object graph. This limit is imposed by the specific provider; other ASP.Net providers aren't obligated to define this limit.

After digging around a bit, I confirmed that there is indeed a limit.

In DefaultSessionStateProvider, located in System.Web.Providers.dll (part of the  Microsoft.AspNet.Providers package):

```
this.MaxSessionSize = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["maxSessionSize"] == null 
    ? 500000 
    : Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["maxSessionSize"], 
        (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This shows you the size (500000), and potentially how to change it (Azure may impose additional constraints on this; I don't know).

However, there is a bigger question: do you really *need* to store so much data in session? Heavy sessions aren't usually a good idea. For one thing, imagine the processing load caused by serializing/deserializing a 500000 byte object graph for every page request.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Finally, I have to use load on-demand to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

one solution I came up with, is to use compression for the sessionState :

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" compressionEnabled="true">
```